# Is someone have solution to error /usr/include/python3.10/pyconfig.h:15: error: arm-linux-gnueabihf/python3.10/pyconfig.h: No such file or directory

Tags: python, c++, qt, debian, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I want to use a Python to made AI in Qt creator, then I need to use couples of libraries(like pybind11) to cross c++ and python. I have problem with that lines in file "python3.10/pyconfig.h":

```
#  include <arm-linux-gnueabihf/python3.10/pyconfig.h>
# elif defined(__ARM_EABI__) && !defined(__ARM_PCS_VFP)
#  include <arm-linux-gnueabi/python3.10/pyconfig.h>
# elif defined(__hppa__)
```

I see the information:

```
/usr/include/python3.10/pyconfig.h:15: error: arm-linux-gnueabihf/python3.10/pyconfig.h: No such file or directory
   15 | #  include <arm-linux-gnueabihf/python3.10/pyconfig.h>
      |            ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
```

I am working on WSL system.

I have tried makings sudo apt-get install... dev,dbg,for python2.7,3,3.8,3.9,3.10,python3.8-dev:armhf. I've tried also download arm separately from http://ftp.de.debian.org/debian/pool/main/p/python3.10/ but I can't save it in /usr/include.. because I don't have permission. I can't edit the file either.

Comment: You have to install the dependencies that contain the header file. I am guessing you are missing to run `sudo apt-get install python-dev` or `sudo apt-get install python3-dev` or a similar packages

Comment: i already done that, like i wrote in post, another ssolutions?